# Why does "tanking" at something mean failing at it?

Tags: etymology, verbs

Why does *tanking* at something mean failing at it?

As an example:

> Mate, I tanked that maths exam.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Tank* came from Tennis jargon, by way of boxing jargon. Originally, it meant to lose on purpose to gain an advantage. You could *tank* a set to get a rest or *tank* a boxing match so your backers could make money gambling against you.

According to [this Slate article](http://www.slate.com/id/2203028/), in the 19th century, Americans called swimming pools "tanks" and thus "go into the tank" was synonymous with "to dive."

Comment: And *to take a dive* is slang for intentionally losing a match.

Comment: ah thanks now I have the connection. to lose -> to dive -> to tank